# Laravel 5.8 Email Verification link or APP_URL return to localhost after deployed on server

Tags: php, laravel

I've configure everything in .env & config/app.php in my Laravel 5.8 for production preparation in heroku like this :

```
APP_NAME=Laraclass
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=xxx
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://larafresh.herokuapp.com
```

And then I try to create an account and check my email verification feature, and the verification link or APP_URL inside the email returns to http://localhost:8000, I've tried to restart my app, and clear the config but still stuck at here. I don't know what happen here, because on another link that I've created (outside of email function), it returns to APP_URL that I've set.

Comment: Pls show your php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clear caching of config.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then restart app.

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: I'm developing in local server and faced this issue and tried this solution but didn't work. I restart server also didn't work and finally when I restarted my pc usually it works

Comment: dont use `php artisan serve` in production server

Answer (score 1):

If you are in server first of all don't try this accepted answer.
Changing on your APP_URL in .env file depends on severel issues.

1. If you're in local machine and do not using queue.
   `php artisan config:clear`
   `php artisan cache:clear`
   `composer dump-autoload`
   `php artisan view:clear`
   `php artisan route:clear`
   That will be enough for change in your local machine.
2. If you're in local machine and using queue.
   `php artisan config:clear`
   `php artisan cache:clear`
   `composer dump-autoload`
   `php artisan view:clear`
   `php artisan route:clear`
   And additionally you have to restart your queue
   `php artisan queue:restart`
   `php artisan queue:work`
3. If you're in server and using queue.
   `php artisan config:clear`
   `php artisan cache:clear`
   `composer dump-autoload`
   `php artisan view:clear`
   `php artisan route:clear`
   And additionally you have to restart your `supervisor`
   `sudo supervisorctl restart all`